# jquery ui tabs activate event not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

All,

I am having trouble getting a handler to run when a new JQuery tab pane is shown.  I am using JQuery 1.6.3 and JQuery-ui 1.8.16.  My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#one">one</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#two">two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
    $(".tabs").tabs({
        select  : function(event,ui) {
            alert("selected a tab");
        },
        activate : function(event,ui) {
            alert("activated a tab");
        }
    });
```

When I click on a tab, the select event fires (I see the alert box) but the activate event doesn't fire (I don't see the alert box).  I don't understand what's wrong.

My goal is to run some code on the various widgets that appear within each tab pane when they are opened.  I would be fine with associating that code with the select event, but that event fires *before* the widgets complete rendering.

How can I run code *after* the widgets in the tab pane have all been rendered?

Thanks.

Comment: I see the opposite... `activate` fires, but not `select`. http://jsfiddle.net/Mng8A/. The [jQueryUI Tabs docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) don't list a `select` event.

Comment: @JasonP: yes, you are correct.  It looks like my combination of JQuery & JQuery-ui library are not behaving as expected.  I'll see about updating to more recent versions.  Thanks.

Comment: That was the issue.  Upgrading the version of JQuery-ui did the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: Are there any workarounds for this version (besides the obvious upgrade)?

Answer (score 2):

JQueryui 1.8 only supports 
    **select** event for tabs.
     **[here is the link](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/)**

starting from JQueryui 1.9 and above removed **select** event. 
instead introduced 
    **activate** event for tabs.
 **[here is the link](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/tabs/)**